# Does the scope of negation change when there is a stressed word within a sentence?

Tags: negation, stress, scope

For example, in the sentence ‘your daughter don’t hate school’, the scope of negation would be entire sentence.

However if 'your' is phonologically stressed like 'YOUR daughter don't hate school', the implication could include the there may be other children who hate school, but your daughter do not.’ Then, does the scope of negation change? Or it has same scope of negation as the former but just the focus is changed?

Comment: Are you asking for native speaker intuitions about this particular example?

Comment: Both variants are incorrect in English.